# Can I deinstall bumblebee if not needed?

Tags: boot, kernel, bumblebee

I run Freya with a 4.2.8 Kernel on a new Intel Skylake NUC i3.
Hardware acceleration of the Intel HD 520 works with "i915.preliminary_hw_support=1" in Grub.

**I don't have any Nvidia hardware.**

On startup bumblebeed tries to start and then quits (cause no Nvidia).
(there are a few dozen fails in dmesg when I look it up)

I think this isn't a big issue but why try to start a process that's not needed anyway?

**So can I safely remove it?** (e.g. with purge)

Or would this result in conflicts with remaining Nvidia drivers in the kernel? (as bumblebee would switch between integrated and dGPU)

Comment: Did this PC have NVIDIA hardware before

Comment: No, it's a Intel NUC6i3SYK, i3 6100U with Intel HD520 graphics.
It just has the integrated graphics.
I checked the install history and it seems that bumblebee is part of the regular elementary OS install or was installed, when I was setting it up. ... and I can't remember that I installed it on purpose.

Comment: Then try upgrading to kernel 4.4LTS .I use that kernel on my AMD laptop and it works perfectly

Comment: Thanks, but I was asking about the bumblebeed process.
I don't run an AMD processor but (as said) an Intel Skylake CPU and internal HD 520 GPU. Totally different thing. Kernels 4.3-4.6 don't run properly on the Skylake NUC at the moment.

Comment: It doesn't matter if you are AMD or Intel. I use the same kernel also on a old Intel

Comment: Try running `sudo apt-get autoremove`

Comment: Sorry, but that both doesn't answer my question: Can I safely remove Bumblebee? (Or could this result in graphics problems?) 
Also: It DOES matter if I'm on AMD, an old or a new Intel processeor because not all NEW hardware is supported by different kernels. And as I said: Kernels 4.3-4.6 (which includes 4.4) do NOT run properly on my Skylake CPU. I get massive graphic glitches with anything above 4.2.8.

Comment: I do not know about Skylake but any CPU should work with 4.4 LTS (remember that it is LTS :).And you should be safe to remove bumblebee if you do not have NVIDIA hardware

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It is safe**

...to remove bumblebee and it's components via `apt-get` as you are not using it.

Comment: Thanks for this short and precise answer to my question.